# Android Bluetooth: java.io.IOException: Unexpected error or truncation during recvmsg

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Tried to implement a Bluetooth SSP server on Android based on the [AcceptThread sample](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).

The main difference was that I kept calling accept() on the server Bluetooth socket to accept additional connections. Whenever accept() returned a socket, I launched a new thread that wrote one byte to the output stream, read one byte from the input stream and closed to client socket.

Made a small C# console app (using the 32feet.NET package) to consume the service that looped and made sequential requests to the Bluetooth server running on Android.

Result - after about 900 successful requests, the Android code crashed with the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Unexpected error or truncation during recvmsg()
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.readba_native(Native Method)
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.access$400(LocalSocketImpl.java:33)
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:98)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:568)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.waitSocketSignal(BluetoothSocket.java:547)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.accept(BluetoothSocket.java:457)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket.accept(BluetoothServerSocket.java:131)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket.accept(BluetoothServerSocket.java:117)
at com.example.david.experimentations.AcceptThread.run(AcceptThread.java:39)
```

Tried running the same server on Galaxy S5 (Android 4.4.2) and Nexus 7 (a later Kitkat), with similar results. I must be doing something stupid (like not properly releasing resources), but I am not sure what. Is there any way of preventing the crash?

Note: the AcceptThread() is launched on a button click from the main activity. Before the aforementioned crash occurs, I can launch the thread as many times as I want. However, after the crash, attempts to call *BluetoothAdapter.createNewRfcommSocketAndRecord()* end up with *java.lang.NullPointerException: FileDescriptor must not be null*.

Links to the source:
[C# Client](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5cf3cb48ee19b42e4e9d)
[AcceptThread](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/58733f00b8c0f27a2d14)
[ExecuteThread](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/548f85d135c2f9a1fa1b)

Comment: You should post the code here, not as links, but your code is poorly structured. For example, in the accept loop, the code that starts the thread depends on the success of the accept() call in the prior try block. It should therefore be *in* that try block.

Comment: Yet another lousy error message from the Bluetooth API. A streaming connection shouldn't have truncation as an error condition.

Comment: @EJP - the code is nearly identical to the official sample I liked, with the main difference being not breaking when accept() returns. I know it's not an excuse to poorly written code, but it still doesn't explain why it fails after some 950+ iterations. Someone in chat suggested trying on an earlier Android version, I will try to get my hands on Gingerbread to see if it differs in any way. Regarding pasting code - is it acceptable to put so much code in here?

Comment: I *linked*, not *liked* :)